# How to find fourier descriptor for set of images

Tags: python, machine-learning, fourier-descriptors

I have a set of images for classification based on shape using machine learning algorithm. How can I find the Fourier descriptor for whole dataset, which can be used as feature for classification?

Comment: Please post a snippet of what you have done till now

Comment: till now only dataset is created ,but now i dont know how to proceed furthur to calculate fourier descriptor of each image in python

Comment: There are lot of online Fourier descriptor snippets available. Check this out : http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_transforms/py_fourier_transform/py_fourier_transform.html